# How to count the number of significant digits?

Tags: matlab

For example, 5.020 would return 4. Preferably, it should work with vector inputs too.

I Googled around and found some answers, but none of them counted the last zero in 5.020.

Comment: Where are you getting these inputs? Can you give us an example? I assume that these numbers are strings of some sort, right?

Comment: Have you tried converting the number to a string and counting the characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given information, it is not possible.

The problem is that when you enter a number it is (per standard) represented as a double, and thus it has a precision of `eps` (the entered precision is lost). However, as one is typically not interested in showing all ~15 digits Matlab uses a couple of different display rules which are independent of the originally entered number, this typically involves the integer part plus 4 digits.

Additionally, the standard rule, when converting a number to a string (`num2str`) is to cutoff trailing zeros. Which is why you do not get the last zero.

Your only option is to count the number of significant digits when you obtain the data. Which leads back to the question @Beaker asks you in the comments